# What database is good for storing Images and Videos?

Tags: mysql, database, image, video

In my project i need to upload my images and videos , those files if i store on Mysql database it gets

slow on get those images.So i store those files on some folder and store those Path on db.Its good , but

i need to know is there any database to store images and videos , and process those in effiecient way ?

Is HBASE is good for that?if it is why we need this huge database for storing images and videos ? Please

get clear this doubt.

Comment: I have read that the best practice is what you have implemented. Images, videos etc are stored onto the server and not inside the database. The reason being that when retrieved the byte stream from the database gives improper output.

Comment: @Vicky Do you store the images as `BLOB` and retrieve them as stream?

Comment: @MArkus MAlKusch Yeah its ok now  ,but in future for more images and videos?it will affect my server performance right?

Comment: @Vicky No it won't. There's is little to none performance gain if you store them directly in the FS. I don't know where this mantra comes that everybody is so reluctant to store blobs in a DBS, I'll try to find that research which compared them both.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] pages clearly state: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. A recommendation for a database would fall under the category of "software library".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing the most efficient environment for serving blobs is not a trivial task. It depends on a lot of factors. See [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525) which made a research only for NTFS and SQL Server 2005. As you can read there it depends absolutely from your personal situation. BTW this was 2006 when BLOB support was a fresh feature. Don't take those number for your setting today! It should just illustrate the complexity of this topic.

My advice is stay with the DBS you feel comfortable with and use its BLOB datatype and a streaming api. This will give you the big advantage that you don't have to care about ACID, replication, a further backup strategy. My guess is that if used properly you won't feel any need for a performance improvement. E.g. SQL Server's Filestream type will give you the identical performance if you'd store it manually in the filesystem.

It is of course a complete different story if you are talking about high volume/frequency data.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use object based storage like Amazon S3 or any other implementation. Biggest benefit is that each uploaded file gets its own HTTP URL so that you can directly load these in your web application.

Comment: Thanks I will Check **Amazon S3** is useful for me or not  , hope it will be ..thanks once again

Comment: Does such a S3 URL provide authorized access?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Last time I checked not. You should check latest documentation. Anyway, each storage with a S3 interface is recommended. Ceph for example can provide this free.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch It does, you can either create signed URLs and pass those to the client (or whatever) side, or pass temporary credentials to the client and let them do the signing themself.

See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html#signing-request-intro

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html