# Integrating data between website and mobile App

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, web, expo

I will be making a website which will fetch some video data from database.

I am also making a mobile app using React-Native expo. I want the **same** data (videos) to be accessible from my React-Native mobile App.

My questions:

1. What is the best way (or best database) to store short videos for website + mobile App?
2. What is the API or the best method followed in industry to fetch the stored videos into a website?
3. What is the API or the best method followed in industry to fetch the **SAME** stored videos into a React-Native (or expo) mobile App?

Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: Will the videos be public or private (like are they for private chats or public videos like youtube)?  If they are public you may want to store them as files on your server.  Private... maybe store their data URI after the user uploads them?  Also just remember that Stack Overflow should be 1 question per question, or else you may be getting lots of flags saying "Needs more focus"

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the questions. Those are related questions. Connected to one another.

Comment: you can check this question about storing videos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330460/what-database-is-good-for-storing-images-and-videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Videos/Photos are usually stored in some file system. Amazon S3 is one option to store such data. You can then save the url to the image/video in your database.

Using that url you can show your video on a website, or mobile app.

For Expo:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/

For web:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do some research on MySQL and NoSQL both of these servers should run parallel to each other one for storing larger, shorter videos files and another one for storing user data and passing links on request.

Comment: usually for videos you'd like an object based storage

Comment: amazon S3 is one example. There are other providers of course